# Prove that the series is absolutely convergent convergent for every $x \in \mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$

So from Leibniz criteria we can see that it is at least conditionally convergent. Now we can use the $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ to compare it with the modules of the series but, I am stuck, so it would be very helpful if someone explained it to me or at least give me some tips on how to transform the sum to something more convenient.

Comment: You can for example use that $(2n+1)! \geq n!$ and compare your series to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(|x|^2)^n}{n!}$.

Comment: Or to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |x|^n/n!$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution i came up with is as follows:

If we take the absolute value of the n-th element of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ and directly apply the ratio test (Dalamber's criteria) - $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\frac{x^{2(n+1)+1}}{(2(n+1)+1)!}}{\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}$ we can almost directly see that it's less than 1, so it is convergent.

Comment: We do not sum over $n$ in the ratio test. You also missed the absolute values.